# How do I set up mod_auth_cas for a VirtualHost?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, cas

I have the following in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/*.conf
```

I have the following in `/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/my_site.conf`:

```
LoadModule auth_cas_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_cas.so
CASCookiePath /tmp/mod_auth_cas/
CASVersion 2
CASDebug on
CASValidateServer off
CASAllowWildcardCert on
CASTimeout 86400
CASIdleTimeout 7200
CASLoginURL https://cas.mycompany.com/cas/login
CASValidateURL https://cas.mycompany.com/cas/serviceValidate
CASCookieDomain hattip-dev.mitre.org

LogLevel debug

<VirtualHost *:80>
  LogLevel debug
  ServerName hattip.local
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/rails_app/public"
  RailsEnv development
  <Location />
    AuthType CAS
    AuthName "MyCompany CAS"
    CASAuthNHeader MOD_AUTH_CAS_USER
    require valid-user
  </Location>
  <directory "/path/to/rails_app/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache will start fine, but every request to my Rails application returns a 403 without redirecting to my CAS server. There is no CAS-related information in the logs, even though `CASDebug` is `on` and `LogLevel` is `debug` everywhere I can think to set it.

PS: I've tried a few variations of the above configuration, including putting the `mod_auth_cas` declarations inside the `<VirtualHost>` definition, but most fail on startup. I've also tried deleting the `<Location>` block and moving that authentication into the `<Directory>` block: no change.

Does anyone know how I can get `mod_auth_cas` to actually redirect to my CAS server?

(Moved from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454685/how-do-i-set-up-modauthcas-for-a-virtualhost))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. The answer was to combine the `<Location>` and `<Directory>` blocks and add a `Satisfy` directive:

```
LoadModule auth_cas_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_cas.so
CASCookiePath /tmp/mod_auth_cas/
CASVersion 2
CASDebug on
CASValidateServer off
CASAllowWildcardCert on
CASTimeout 86400
CASIdleTimeout 7200

LogLevel debug

<VirtualHost *:80>
  CASCookieDomain "myapp"
  CASLoginURL "https://cas.mycompany.com/cas/login"
  CASValidateURL "https://cas.mycompany.com/cas/serviceValidate"
  LogLevel debug
  ServerName "myapp"
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/rails_app/public"
  RailsEnv development
  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    AuthType CAS
    AuthName "MyCompany CAS"
    require valid-user
    Satisfy Any
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```